# How do I check if an object is null

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a CrudRepository class that I get employee from by their email address.

```
val existingEmployee: Employee? = employeeManagementService.findEmployeeByEmail(employeeData.email)
```

How do i check if existingEmployee returns with a null

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
existingEmployee?.let { 

    //Do your stuffs

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scoping functions:

```
existingEmployee?.let { it ->
 //Employee not null
} ?: //employee is null
```

or go with the old fashion:

```
 if (existingEmployee != null) { 

 }
```

Comment: The first method worked. I had used the second method and it returns true no matter what. Thank you.

Comment: the construct `x?.let { ... } ?: ...` does not work! It's not an equivalent of if-else, since the code behind the elvis operator *will* be executed if the let block returns something that is not null.  See [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-the-elvis-operator-da536ba68161)

Comment: @FrankNeblung If the `existingEmployee` object is not null, the code inside the `let` scope function will execute. I do not know exactly how the OP wants his code to execute, I included the Elvis operator just to demonstrate the available option.

Comment: @FrankNeblung elvis code will run either when x is null or let returns null.

Comment: See [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.149940913.628297884.1596732076-1110864201.1595450643#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiLyoqXG4gKiBZb3UgY2FuIGVkaXQsIHJ1biwgYW5kIHNoYXJlIHRoaXMgY29kZS4gXG4gKiBwbGF5LmtvdGxpbmxhbmcub3JnIFxuICovXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBleGlzdGluZ0VtcGxveWVlID0gXCJleGlzdGluZ1wiXG4gICAgZXhpc3RpbmdFbXBsb3llZT8ubGV0IHsgcHJpbnRsbihpdCk7IG51bGwgfSA/OiBwcmludGxuKFwiZWx2aXNcIilcbn0ifQ==) both branches being executed

Comment: That's alright, but I just don't understand how that is relevant to what the OP mentioned in his code. But, the info you added will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is very good and I advise you to read it properly. The nullability topic is discussed [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions), specifically to answer your question:

```
val b: String? = "Kotlin"
if (b != null && b.length > 0) {
    print("String of length ${b.length}")
} else {
    print("Empty string")
}
```